# How to fix javascript timer so that seconds run up to 60 and then reset to zero

Tags: javascript, timer

I'm setting up a timer, but currently the seconds run into the thousands instead of resetting to zero after 60 seconds. Is there a quick fix for this?
This is the code I'm using:

```
var running = 0;
function startPause(){
if(running == 0){
    running = 1;
    increment();
    document.getElementById("start").innerHTML = "Pause";
}else{
    running = 0;
    document.getElementById("start").innerHTML = "Resume";
}
};

function reset(){
running = 0;
time = 0;
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "00:00";
document.getElementById("start").innerHTML = "Start";
};
function increment(){
if(running == 1){
    setTimeout(function(){
        time++;
        var mins = Math.floor(time / 10 / 60);
        if(mins <= 9){
            mins = "0" + mins;
        }
        var secs = Math.floor(time / 10);
        if(secs <= 9){
            secs = "0" + secs;
        }
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = mins + ":" + secs;
        increment();
    }, 100);
}};
```

Comment: This sounds like an opportune time to use a debugger.  When you step through your code in your debugger, where specifically do you expect the "seconds" to become 0?  Which line of code is doing that?  When you debug, what happens when you get to that line of code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use modulo **% 60**.

It gives the Rest of the division by 60

example 127 % 60 = 7

Comment: Thanks for your answer nbk. Could you show me where in the code to add %60?

Comment: Math.floor(time%60); gives the seconds. bus You can use var secs = Math.floor(time / 10&60); But i'm not sure why you make your div 10.

Answer (score 0):

I made a custom audio player and this helped me.

```
if (seconds != 0 && seconds % 60 == 0) {
  seconds = 0;
  minutes++;
}
```